# javafx copy function of current node to another node

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create a new button by click exist original button as below code shows. Now I hope the new button have same function as current button. When I click the new button, it will also create new button. If original button have more functions, and new button can also have these functions.

```
Button btn = new Button("Original Button");

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    btn.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        root.getChildren().add(new Button("New button"));
    });
```

Comment: There is no way around doing this by copying every single event handler, e.g. `Button oldButton = (Button) e.getSource(); Button newButton = new Button(...); newButton.setOnMouseClicked(oldButton.getOnMouseClicked());`. However event handlers added using `addEventHandler` cannot be enumerated (at least not without accessing private members via reflection). BTW: Note that usually the `onAction` event is used for buttons instead of `onMouseClicked`, since the former event is also triggered on pressing enter when the button is focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code from @fabian suggestions:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication11 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Button oldButton = (Button)event.getSource();                
                Button newButton = new Button("new Button");
                vbox.getChildren().add(newButton);
                newButton.setOnAction(oldButton.getOnAction());               
            }
        });


        vbox.getChildren().add(btn);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```